# How to new a class by name that defined in the field of type in generics class

Tags: java, generics

I want use java generics to implement function like this:

```
public class Test<T> {
    public T data;

    public Test() {
        data = new T();
    }
}
```

but the java compile report a error like "Cannot instantiate the type T",how to implement this function in java ?

Answer (score 4):

You need the class

```
public Test(Class<? extends T> klass) {
    data = klass.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Please don't use reflection unnecessarily.

Comment: how is this "reflection unnecessarily"?

Comment: ;) since `class` is a keyword

Comment: Yes, this solution works, but there are some downsides: (1) It assumes the class has a zero-argument constructor.  If the class does not have such a constructor, then a runtime exception will be thrown (the compiler won't catch it). (2) It uses reflection, which is slower than regular code (you shouldn't use reflection on a regular basis).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline fixed the code, tks.  Don't understand the unnecessarily reflection.

Comment: @Michael I don't know how you will ever be able to supply parameters to the newly created instance's constructor from a generic class.  And reflection beein slower, yes, but probably on 99% of applications it is not noticeable.

Comment: @krico There is clearly no need to bring reflection in here. All we need is a very simple abstract factory (or similar).

Comment: @krico It's possible to invoke a non-default constructor using reflection.  For example: `T instance = klass.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.class).newInstance("myString", 42);`  Yes, I would agree that performance loss from using reflection is not noticeable in most situations.  But performance aside, you are bypassing the compiler when using reflection, which means you must be extra careful or else runtime exceptions will appear.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tacklin I think that without reflection it beats the purpose of the question.  If you have the "supplier" you might as well just keep the ocde as "Test tst = new Test(supplier.get());"...

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution to this would be to provide a `Supplier` or factory for `T`.

```
public class Test<T>{
     public T data;

     public Test(Supplier<T> supplier){
        data = supplier.get();
     }

     // or

     public Test(T t){
        data = t;
     }

}
```

Comment: (For "advanced" use (say to be released as part of the API), the constructor should read `public Test(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {`. If you require a supplier of apples, a supplier of McIntoshes is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because Java implements generics by erasure.

See the answers to this similar question for more details:

- [Java Generics, Create an instance of Class<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045829/java-generics-create-an-instance-of-classt)

Comment: is there some way of substitute?

Comment: @user1010434: Yes, you can either use a pattern like kriko's answer, or you can just require the code calling the constructor to provide you with a `T` directly.

Comment: @user1010434 Just use an abstract factory (as it stands, there's no way to know if `T` has an accessible no-args constructor (C# has some extra syntax to specify required constructors)).